# ReactJS How can I push a data from SelectField to an object within an array?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, reactjs

I have an array which you can see below. How can I insert data from a Selectfield into prints.printMethod?

```
selectedOrder: {
  category: {},
  product: {},
  brand: {},
  prints: {
    printMethod: {},
    height: '',
    width: '',
    colors: ''
  }
}
```

My code below is the onChange function. I am not sure if I am missing something. I hope someone can help me.

```
onBrandingsChange = (event, index, value) => {
    var newSelect = this.state.selectedOrder;
    newSelect.prints.push(value);
    this.setState({selectedOrder: newSelect});
  }

 <SelectField value={this.state.selectedOrder.prints.printMethod} onChange={this.onBrandingsChange}>
    {_.map(this.state.brandings, (b) => {
      return <MenuItem value={b.name} primaryText={b.name} key={b.id}/>;
    })}
</SelectField>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prints` is an Object not an array type so push can't be used here.

You can assign the value to the key directly if you wish it to be single depth.

Something like:

```
onBrandingsChange = (event, index, value) => {
    var newSelect = this.state.selectedOrder;
    // set it
    newSelect.prints.printMethod = value
    // or use assign
    newSelect.prints = Object.assign(newSelect.prints, { printMethod: value });

    this.setState({selectedOrder: newSelect});
}
```

Of if you wish this to be an array you need to change the types of your `selectedOrder` state.